# Install git Raspbian Jessie lite

Tags: raspbian, jessie-lite, git

```
sudo apt-get install git-core

Package git-core is a virtual package provided by:
  git 1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'git-core' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas as the why I cannot install git?

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
[sudo] password for chris: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  git-svn git-man git-el

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Here's the sources list in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**it was problem to clone wiringPi** 
The following error... using MAC

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
-bash: git: command not found
```

I used the following method and it worked

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install git
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd wiringPi
pi@raspberrypi:~/wiringPi $ ./build
```

Answer (score 11):

Install git rather than git-core.

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your package manager is out of date. Before installing, it's usually wise to update it by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once that's done, you should be able to install it with the command you used before

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: I always do, still doesn't work

Comment: @Jacomb001 : I have done these, and it goes through an update process. and go through install and it tells me I have the latest version, but I am still on 2.1, and 2.12 is out..

Comment: @WORMSS: the package managers are not always on the latest revision. It takes time for them to check updates for compatibility and then compile them for all the various architectures.